# mrg1 = pd.merge(df_results,df_constructors,on='constructorId') This shows a key error all the time

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Tried changing the column name but still shows `key error`. Tried it with another Dataframe still says `key error` for the column `i` need to merge

```
mrg1 = pd.merge(df_results, df_constructors, on='constructorId')
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mentioned renaming and merging of dfs, which they are not related to each other.

For merging dfs in `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

#Generating random samples
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df1.insert(0, 'constructorId', range(1,11))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('CD'))
df2.insert(0, 'constructorId', range(1,11))

#merging df1 and df2
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='constructorId',how="inner")
```

For renaming:

```
#rename one column
df3.rename({'constructorId': 'id'}, axis=1,inplace=True)

#OR

#renmae all columns
df3.columns=["id","Z","Y","X","W"]
```

For more detail check [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)